# JQGrid Displaying Server Errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I have tried several solutions found here and elsewhere on the web but I still can't get the server sent errors to properly display on the jqgrid edit form. I have put breakpoints in the afterSubmit method of the jqgrid but it's never hit. I have simplified it to just show an alert if the method is executed but nothing is working. What I end up with is the stacktrace displayed into the header of the edit form. What did I miss?

JQGrid Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#JQGrid1").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "InvoiceType")',
            editurl: '@Url.Action("EditData", "InvoiceType")',
            mtype: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            page: 1,
            colModel: [
                { editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: "readonly" }, key: true, width: 60, label: "Id", name: "Id", hidden: false },
                { editable: true, width: 250, label:"Name", name: "Name", hidden: false },
                { editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: "readonly" }, width: 175, label: "Date Created", name: "DateCreated", align: 'right', hidden: false, formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A" } },
                { editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: "readonly" }, width: 175, label: "Date Updated", name: "DateUpdated", align: 'right', hidden: false, formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A" } },
                { editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: "readonly" }, width: 200, label: "Created By", name: "UpdatedBy", hidden: false },
                //{ editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: "readonly" }, width: 50, label: "Active", name: "Active", hidden: false },
                { editable: true, editoptions: { value: "1:0" }, edittype: "checkbox", width: 50, label: "Active", name: 'Active', index: 'Active', formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', stype: "select", searchoptions: { value: "1:Yes;0:No" } },
            ],
            height: "350",
            autowidth:true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            caption: "Invoice Types",
            rowNum: 10,
            pager: "#JQGrid1_pager",
            rowattr: function (rd) {
                if (rd.Active === 'False') {
                    return { "class": "myAltRowClass" };
                }
            },
            loadComplete: function () {
                //alert("OK");
            },
            loadError: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + "\n" +
                    'textStatus: ' + textStatus + "\n" +
                    'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
                alert('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + "\n" + jqXHR.responseText);
            },

        }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#JQGrid1_pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, view: true, refresh: true },
        {
            // edit options
            editCaption: "The Edit Dialog",
            recreateForm: true,
            checkOnUpdate: true,
            checkOnSubmit: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width:'auto',
            errorTextFormat: function (response) {
                return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" ' +
                             'style="float:left; margin-right:.3em;"></span>' +
                            response.responseText;
            },
            afterSubmit: function (response) {
                var myInfo = '<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">' +
                             '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" ' +
                                 'style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' +
                             response.responseText +
                             '</div>',
                    $infoTr = $("#TblGrid_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + ">tbody>tr.tinfo"),
                    $infoTd = $infoTr.children("td.topinfo");
                $infoTd.html(myInfo);
                $infoTr.show();

                // display status message to 3 sec only
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $infoTr.slideUp("slow");
                }, 3000);

                return [true, "", ""]; // response should be interpreted as successful
            }

        },
        {
            //add options
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
            }

        },
        {
            // del options
            errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
            }
        },
        {
            //search

        },
        {
            //view details form
            height: 'auto',
            width: '400',
        });
    });

</script>
```

Web API Controller Method Code

```
[ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseMessage))]
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody] InvoiceTypeModel item)
{
    if (item == null)
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not read Invoice Type from body");

    InvoiceType originalItem = db.InvoiceTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    if (originalItem == null || originalItem.Id != id)
    {
        item.Id = 0;
        Post(item);
    }

    InvoiceType nameMatchItem = db.InvoiceTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == item.Name);
    if (nameMatchItem != null && nameMatchItem.Id != item.Id)
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "You can't have more than one record with the same name");

    if (ModelState.IsValid && id == item.Id)
    {
        try
        {
            item.Id = id;
            ObjectHelper.CopyPropertyValues(item, originalItem);
            db.InvoiceTypes.ApplyCurrentValues(originalItem);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Record not found");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string c = ex.Message;
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Update Successful");
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not save to the database.");
    }
}
```

Here's the Web Page Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditData(string oper, int? Id, string Name, DateTime? DateCreated, int? Active)
{
    InvoiceTypeModel cn = new InvoiceTypeModel();
    switch (oper)
    {
        case "add":
        {
            cn.Id = 0;
            cn.Name = Name;
            cn.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            cn.UpdatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
            cn.Active = true;
            _invoiceTypeRepository.Create(cn);
            return Content("true");
        }
        case "del":
        {
            _invoiceTypeRepository.Delete((int) Id);
            return Content("true");
        }
        case "edit":
        {
            cn.Id = (int) Id;
            cn.Name = Name;
            cn.DateCreated = (DateTime) DateCreated;
            cn.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            cn.UpdatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
            cn.Active = Active == 1;
            _invoiceTypeRepository.Upsert(cn);
            return Content("true");
        }
    }
    return Content("false");
}
```

Here's a partial screenshot of the edit form after it receives the error. It's the correct information, a 409 Conflict but the formatting is not happening properly.

[image]

Comment: your pointing  method name is the problem i think because you are using method name "Put" but it should be "InvoiceType" maens the controller name.////url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "InvoiceType")'

Comment: When I submit the edit form it goes through the web controller to the web api controller and trips the proper error.I just don't get the response to display.

Comment: intially try to debug the web api what is the response you are getting from service....otherwise post web api code here too

Comment: The web api code is there. It's the second section of code. I am gettin g the proper response back PostMan shows me this {
  "Message": "You can't have more than one record with the same name"
}

Comment: ok so your flow of code is like this first it goes to PUT(i.e web api ) that returns message ..after that it goes to "EditData"..am i right?

Comment: No. The web Page JQGrid calls EditData() in it's page controller. The Page Controller's call goes up to the PUT in the WEB API

Comment: code looks good np is their @Tim you have to debug it in console

Comment: Still coming up the same. Anyone else have any suggestions?